# RealmSwift configuration url changing makes Fabric and Firebase integration to fail

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, realm, google-fabric

I've changed my realm files location cause `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` and `UIFileSharingEnabled` are enabled for my app and I don't want that user has the ability to delete realm files.

```swift
var configuration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

var fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(
    for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask
)[0]
configuration.fileURL = fileURL
let realm = try? Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

Causes Firebase and Fabric fail:

```
6.1.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS0...] Failed to recreate database file.
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “Application Support” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Library”."
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/01E67E95-1/data/Containers/Data/Application/61B1CB70-1/Library/Application Support,
 NSUnderlyingError=0x600001666d60{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"}}
```

And a similar error for Fabric.
If I don't change realm configurations fileUrl then Everything will work.
Any idea why and how to fix.